# Trying to compare a value to a value in a python two-dimensional list, but comparison fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm currently working on a battleship game and I'm setting ship coordinates in a list. Everything works fine, but when I check to make sure I'm not setting an already existing coordinate the check doesn't work.

```
ship_locations = []

for i in range(4):
    # Get random values(0-4) and assign to ship_row and ship_col
    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board)

    # Set the first pair of coordinates in ship_locations
    ship_locations.append([ship_row, ship_col])

    # Check if ship_locations[i][n] is equal to ship_row and ship_col
    # This is where I'm having problems
    if ship_row == ship_locations[i][0] and ship_col == ship_locations[i][1]:
        continue
    else:
        ship_locations[i] = [ship_row, ship_col]

print(ship_locations)


OUTPUT: [[3, 2], [4, 4], [4, 4], [3, 0]]
```

I've tried different variations of the check and it's still not working. Any ideas what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just iterating over from `1` to `4` and simply checking only one element in the `if ship_row == ship_locations[i][0] and ship_col == ship_locations[i][1]:` line, whereas you need to iterate over the whole list to check if the new combination lies within it or not, So the logic may look like this:

```
ship_locations = []
while (len(ship_locations) < 4):
    ship_row = random_row(board)
    ship_col = random_col(board)

    if ([ship_row, ship_col] not in ship_locations):
        ship_locations.append([ship_row, ship_col])
print ship_locations
```